# How to combine multiple queries in Slack?

Tags: search, slack

In Slack, is it possible in a single query to get:

- all messages from John with the word `car` in it;
- all messages from Jane with the word `boat` in it.

The results should be combined and chronologically ordered. I tried

```
(from:@john car) OR (form:@jane boat)
```

but apparently Slack does not support brackets when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this is unfortunately not supported. The [documentation](https://slack.com/help/articles/202528808-Search-in-Slack) doesn't mention any operators like that and if you add two usernames to your search, you can see in the <kbd>Filter By</kbd> menu that they're always combined into an `AND` type of search.

If you are an admin, a workaround is to [export the data](https://slack.com/help/articles/201658943-Export-your-workspace-data) and then use 3rd party tools to search through it. Or use [API](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) if you have access and combine two searches.